# How do i return date with MMDDYYYY format as a valid date value in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am trying to validate the date field for the various combination. While trying to validate MMDDYYYY, the function does not return it as valid. also, it does not give proper input for MMDDYY, MMMDDYY, MMMDDYYYY.

```
SET DATEFORMAT mdy;

IF ISDATE('11202018') = 1  
    PRINT 'Valida date field' 
ELSE  
    PRINT 'INVALID';
```

The date in above example is a valid date field, still, it returns invalid. I doubt SQL server is considering the local date setting.

Can anyone share your thought?

Comment: I know it doesn't really answer your question per se, but if you always pass date literals in YYYY-MM-DD format and the problem goes away.

Comment: Thanks. Yes if i use field date separator e.g mm/dd/yy, it works fine else it is not working

Comment: SQL server won't consider the local date setting. `ISDATE()` will work based on your `SET DATEFORMAT` and `SET LANGUAGE`

Comment: It works only when i use separators but for MMM/DD/YYYY, i am not able to validate even

Comment: if that "date field" is a string then for the love of humanity stop now and use a date field instead, then your validations problems are solved.

Answer (score 1):

The ONLY safe date literal without delimiters is `'YYYYMMDD'`
(style 102)

(in fact it remains "the safest", even a `'YYYY-MM-DD'` literal can get messed up by a French language setting. see ref below)

You will NOT get `ISDATE()` to recognize `'MMDDYYYY'` without manipulating the string to insert delimiters.

[Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the separators first, before using ISDATE function

```
DECLARE @DATE nvarchar(100) = '11202018'

IF ISDATE(SELECT(STUFF(STUFF(@DATE,3,0,'-'),6,0,'-')))
       PRINT 'Valida date field' 
ELSE  
    PRINT 'INVALID';
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server works based on the DATEFORMAT,
Before going to check should separate the date filed by "/" or "-"

Refer the query, It will works both "MMM/DD/YYYY" and "mm/dd/yy"

```
IF ISDATE('11/20/2018') = 1  
    PRINT 'VALID'  
ELSE  
    PRINT 'INVALID';
```